# Как работают операции |= и &=~

Tags: c++, c

Помогите разобраться что делает эта строчка:

```
PORTX |= (1 << 2);
PORTX &= ~(1 << 2);
```

Ну совсем не могу понять что это такое |= или &=~...
Можете пояснить на примере эти строчки....

Comment: если кратко, то первое выражение взводит 3-й бит, второе выражение гасит 3-й бит.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[битовые операции в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

`PORTX |= (1 << 2);` - это сокращенная запись `PORTX = PORTX | (1 << 2);`

`PORTX &= ~(1 << 2);` - это сокращенная запись `PORTX = PORTX & ~(1 << 2);`

теперь по частям:

`<<` - оператор [побитового сдвига](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8xftzc7e.aspx). сдвигает биты на 2 влево у числа 1. В общем, получается 4, то есть `(1 << 2) == 4`.

`~` - побитовое НЕ. грубоговоря - инвертирует биты.

`|` - это побитовое ИЛИ. то есть запись вида `PORTX =  PORTX | 4;` устанавливает 2-й бит числа PORTX в единицу.

`&` - это побитовое И. запись вида `PORTX & 4` "извлекает" 2-й бит из числа (то есть `PORTX & 4 == 0` когда 2-й бит равен 0 и `PORTX & 4 != 0` когда 2-й бит равен 1)

Запись вида `PORTX & ~4` извлекает все биты, кроме 2-го.

**UPD:** поправил про битность. См. 1<<2 - это то же самое, что 1 * 2^2 = 4. Т.е. в двоичной системе - 100b. Т.е. установлен второй бит. Соответственно, с бинарными операциями то же самое. Когда мы применяем `PORTX & 4`, то мы оставляем 2-й бит, а остальные сбрасываем. Если мы напишем `PORTX | 2`, то мы установим 1-й бит.

P.S. вообще по логике биты в байте нужно нумеровать не с 1, а с 0. И тогда пост нужно поправить еще раз. :-(

**UPD:** поправил сам. биты отсчитываются с нуля.

Comment: Спасибо всем вам за первый и 2-й ответы!!!!! Понял!)

Comment: @MaxXx1313 Как-то не очень аккуратно у вас вышло. 1<<2 - это третий бит, а не 4-й.

Comment: Почему? сдвигаем же... обьясните, не понял вас Yura Ivanov

Comment: @Aller, если с нуля считать (обычно так принято), то вообще второй.

    1 это ...0001  // 1      нулевой бит
    2  -  ...0010  // 1<<1   первый бит
    4  -  ...0100  // 1<<2   второй бит
    8  -  ..01000  // 1<<3

и т.д.

Comment: Да, если с нуля считать то 2-й бит. Если с единицы (как разряды в обычных системах счисления), то третий, третий разряд. Но никак не четвертый.

Answer (score 8):

`|=` это  оператор присвоения битового "или", аналогичен

```
a |= b ->  a = a | b
```

~  битовая инверсия - операция, изменяющая в переменной все 0 на 1 и все 1 на 0.

&= оператор присвоения битового "и"

```
a &= b -> a = a & b
```

Comment: Какие же они унарные, когда есть левая (то, что изменяется) и правая (то, как изменяется) части?

Comment: Эээ, согласен, лоханулся.